# how to pass a php var through jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i have this script on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patrioticcow/HysJ6/) .

when i click on the links i get another view.

What i am trying to do is replace

```
<a id="mine_click" href="#">test</a>
```

with:

```
$test = 'here we go'
<a id="mine_click" href="?var=$test">test</a>
```

and pass the `$test` var to the `tab3`view when i click on the `test` link,

so that the result will be `2222 here we go`

any ideas on how to pass a php var through a link going through jquery?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to pass information from php to javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597134/how-to-pass-information-from-php-to-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that it is exactly what you need.

You have a php variable from the server side. In your javascript code you can do

```
var foo = '<?php echo $test; ?>';
```

and then you can use `foo` as a javascript variable

```
$('#mine_click').attr('href','?var='+foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
var test = '<?php echo($test) ?>';
$('#mine_click').attr('href', '?var='+test);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
?var=<?php echo $test; ?>
```

will do the stuff

```
$('#mine_click').attr('href', '?var=<?php echo $test; ?>');
```